# C# ZipFile throwing exceptions after successfull operation

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I'm trying to compress a folder of images (2000 or so) into a .zip file  using [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET 4.5.2

The following code creates the .zip file successfully:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string startPath= @"D:\Photos";
    string zipPath = @"D:\Photos\all.zip";

    //Same issue with CompressionLevel.Optimal
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);

    Console.Write("Done! ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The zip file is created and filled with all the images, but then the method starts throwing exception, one `System.IO.IOException in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` telling me that the folder is already in use by another process and then `System.IO.IOException in mscorlib.dll` telling me all.zip already exists in the target directory, this one gets thrown continuously, seemingly without end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably the problem is in compress output being in the same folder as files to be compressed. The function tries to compress the file `D:\Photos\all.zip` since the file mask does not specify that this file should not be compressed.

Comment: Thanks! i didnt think that would be a problem, i changed the target folder and now it's working properly, although i would prefer to use the same folder for the images and the zip.

Comment: @HiSpy you can always move it afterwards

Comment: @phuzi It's probably what i'm gonna do, i guess my newness to file manipulation is showing!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 string startPath = @"E:\testPage";
 string zipPath = @"E:\testPage.zip";

 //Same issue with CompressionLevel.Optimal
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);

 Console.Write("Done! ");
 Console.ReadKey();
```

You are reading the folder and creating the zip in the same path and hence you get the error the folder is alredy in use by another process

Change your zip path. It should then work.